# Multiple Modals Same Page Using Simple Jquery (Responsive on Deskop and Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I've made up a Modal that works perfectly on desktop but on mobile when I click outside the modal area the screen stays open,

Is there a way to fix this for mobile? or do I have to include the 'X' to close?

I tried including

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#port-content-1").hide('fast');
});

$("#port-content-1").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

instead of

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

but when I click the button the modal appears and instantly closes for some reason,

Also if there's a way to make multiple modals for different videos I'd appreciate any easy fix! - I have looked around on stack for similar articles but they involve a completely different method, seems as I got one working perfectly would be good to know if it can be done for more instead of scrapping it.

The code I'm referring to is: https://jsfiddle.net/joshtrose/g80vknyL/

Comment: For multiple Modals I think the best way would be to declare a function that checks the id of the modal and then shows the right one, if anyone can post that in a way that's relevant to my code I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed both problems with:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
var modal = $(this).data("modal");
$(modal).show();
});

$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
var className = e.target.className;
if(className === "modal" || className === "close"){
  $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
}
});
```

Found it here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-get-this-script-to-work-for-multiple-modal-popups/252443/7

Such an efficient solution the guys on there are legends.